# What does the BIOS-Option Hotstart mean?

Tags: bios

I have an option in my BIOS called "Hotstart". I can enable and disable it, but I don't know what it means.

Comment: What motherboard/BIOS mfg is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your firmware supports [Windows HotStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463098).

Comment: Do I have any advantage of it if I use Linux? Should I enable or disable it?